# SQL update part of string

Tags: sql

Table name: blist

```
serial_no   city
abcd_086    US
abcd_087    US
abcd_088    US
abcd_089    US
abcd_090    US
```

Any sql query which can replace abcd_086 ,087, etc to xyz_086,087,etc.
Need to replace first 4 char of serial_no column with xyz.
Please help!!!

Comment: Tag spam doesn't help us help you; don't do it. Just tag what is relevant to your question. Speaking of your question, what is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace it

```
update blist
set serial_no = replace(serial_no, 'abcd_', 'xyz_')
where city = 'US'
  and serial_no like 'abcd%'
```

[Demo](https://www.mycompiler.io/view/IdhboQb)

Answer (score 0):

the result may vary depending on database. But all of them is close approach. I use postgres db.

```
UPDATE "blist"
SET "serial_no" = CONCAT('xyz',SUBSTRING("serial_no",5));
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL provides a very helpful string function called REPLACE that allows you to replace all occurrences of a substring in a string with a new substring.

```
UPDATE students
SET serial_no = REPLACE(serial_no, 'abcd_', 'xyz_');
WHERE city = 'US' and serial_no like 'abcd_%';

SELECT * FROM STUDENT;
```

Here, you get the [Demo](https://www.mycompiler.io/new/sql)

Answer (score 0):

ANSI SQL way to *replace first 4 char of serial_no column with xyz*:

```
update blist
set serial_no = 'xyz' || substring(serial_no from 5)
```